# Why is there a StackOverflowError in the following Java code?

Tags: java

Given the following code:

```
 public class Classa {

     int x=10;

     void func(){

     }

     Classa inner=new Classa(){
         void func(){
                 x=90;
         }

     };

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Classa c=new Classa();
         c.inner.func();

     }
 }
```

Why does my app crashes during instantiating? (accourding to debugger)
It goes into some kind of infinite recursive. Any idea?

Comment: Recursive constructor calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling new Classa(). This triggers the class to construct.

Think now, how does the `inner` variable get instantiated? On the constructor call, it recursively calls `inner = new Classa()`

So now what happens from that call? The process recursively repeats until you get your stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

Because you have

```
Classa inner=new Classa()
```

which is equivalent to

```
class Classa {
  Classa inner;

  Classa() {
    inner = new Classa();
  }
}
```

which keeps instantiating an inner variable which is of the same type of the containing class, thus creating an infinite amount of instances.

**To initialise a `Classa` instance you need to allocate the inner variable which is of `Classa` type**, here it is the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `new Classa()` from inside your Classa constructor.

Answer (score 1):

While you are trying to construct a new `Classa` object, the instance variable `inner` gets initialized as part of the construction process, which caused another call to the `Classa` constructor, thus the code gets into a endless recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance variable `inner` that is defined in your class.  You are initializing it to an anonymous subclass of `Classa`.  This will create another instance of `Classa`.  But that new instance will attempt to create its own `inner`, resulting in an infinite loop of calls to creating an instance of `Classa`.  Each call places things on the stack, and eventually a `StackOverflowError` results.

One way to stop it would be to make `inner` `static`, so there is only one `inner` for the entire class:

```
static Classa inner = new Classa(){
```